# Como limpiar el buffer de entrada?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo txt, tengo que ingresar 30 campos, pero llega un momento que cuando lee un **cout** ya no me pide valores, el problema es cuando ingresas un dato tipo `int` y despues una cadena de texto, como puedo limpiar el **buffer** para que no cache los `'\n'`

```
cout<<"informativo:  "; //1.-CADENA
cin.getline(informativo,20);

cout<<"nivel_desactualizada:  ";  //2.-CADENA
cin.getline(nivel_desactualizada,3);

cout<<"abierta_cerrada:  ";  //3.-CADENA
cin.getline(abierta_cerrada,10);

cout<<"member_code:  ";  //NUMERICO
cin>>member_code;
cin.ignore();

cout<<"member kob:  ";  //CADENA
cin.getline(member_kob,2);

cout<<"no_cuenta:  ";   //CADENA
cin.getline(no_cuenta,16);
```

Comment: Lo pongo como comentario, porque estoy **seguro** de que la pregunta está duplicada: `cin.ignore( numeric_limits< streamsize >::max( ), '\n' );`.

Comment: Algunos se evitan el problema leyendo todo como cadena y luego haciendo conversiones

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz eso es como reinventar la rueda... y el problema solo lo encuentras cuando trabajas con `getline`

Answer (score 2):

> como puedo limpiar el buffer para que no cache los `'\n'`

Ya lo estás haciendo:

```
cout<<"member_code:  ";  //NUMERICO
cin>>member_code;
cin.ignore(); // <<--- AQUI!!!
```

Esa llamada elimina el primer caracter del buffer de entrada.
Las diferentes sobrecargas del operador de extracción `>>` no eliminan los saltos de línea o espacios que haya después de la lectura... lo que hacen es ignorar estos caracteres antes de empezar la lectura. Así, el siguiente ejemplo leera dos enteros independientemente de si los separas con espacios (uno, dos o los que sean) o saltos de línea:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::cout << a << '-' << b;
```

En tu caso el programa está funcionando correctamente... lo único *raro*  es la lectura del campo que sigue al entero:

```
cout<<"member kob:  ";  //CADENA
cin.getline(member_kob,2);
```

En esta lectura le estás diciendo a `cin` que no puede almacenar más de dos caracteres en `member_kob`... teniendo en cuenta que uno de ellos va a ser sí o sí el finalizador de cadena (`\0`), nos queda que en `member_kob` va a almacenar únicamente un caracter.

Si no necesitas leer espacios es preferible usar `std::string` y el operador de extracción `>>`. La solución será más limpia y te dará menos dolores de cabeza:

```
std::string informativo;
cout<<"informativo:  "; //1.-CADENA
cin >> informativo;

std::string nivel_desactualizada;
cout<<"nivel_desactualizada:  ";  //2.-CADENA
cin >> nivel_desactualizada;

cout<<"abierta_cerrada:  ";  //3.-CADENA
cin.getline(abierta_cerrada,10);

int member_code;
cout<<"member_code:  ";  //NUMERICO
cin>>member_code;

std::string member_kob;
cout<<"member kob:  ";  //CADENA
cin >> member_kob;

std::string no_cuenta;
cout<<"no_cuenta:  ";   //CADENA
cin >> no_cuenta;
```

O, si en algun campo resulta que es posible encontrar espacios:

```
std::string informativo;
cout<<"informativo:  "; //1.-CADENA
getline(cin,informativo);
```

En este último caso sí que tendrás que preocuparte de volver a eliminar el salto de línea residual después de usar el operador `>>`:

```
int member_code;
cout<<"member_code:  ";  //NUMERICO
cin>>member_code;
cin.ignore();

std::string member_kob;
cout<<"member kob:  ";  //CADENA
getline(cin,member_kob);
```

Eso sí, hay una forma más genérica de usar el método `ignore`, y es pidiéndole que descarte **todos** los caracteres que encuentre hasta el primer salto de línea (que también se descartará):

```
#include <limits>

cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```